# Removing database.yml when using Mongoid in Rails 3.2

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, mongodb, mongoid

I just began a new rails project and wanted to use MongoidDB thru the Mongoid gem.  Following the instructions on the Mongoid site, I added the following lines to my `Gemfile`:

```
gem "mongoid", "~> 2.4"
gem "bson_ext", "~> 1.5"
```

I then proceeded to removing my `database.yml` file as per the instructions [here](http://mongoid.org/docs/installation/configuration.html). My `application.rb` file now looks like so:

```
require "action_controller/railtie"
require "action_mailer/railtie"
require "active_resource/railtie"
require "rails/test_unit/railtie"
require "sprockets/railtie" # Uncomment this line for Rails 3.1+
```

Now, when I use `rails s` to start my server in development, I get the following errors:

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/railties-3.2.0/lib/rails/railtie/configuration.rb:85:in `method_missing': undefined method `active_record' for #<Rails::Application::Configuration:0x007ff38b20d0b0> (NoMethodError)
```

I tried looking for a solution, but it seems no one has yet to come across my problem.  Am I doing something wrong? Is this caused by the recent Rails 3.2 update?

Thanks for your help!

**UPDATE (Jan 26):**
Based on the info from Dylan Markow, I used the terminal command

```
grep -r active_record config/
```

And put any refrences to active_record in comment blocks.

I have a simple controller with one action that does not even hit the database yet. When I access the action via browser I get

```
ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished (ActiveRecord::ConnectionNotEstablished):
  activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:374:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:168:in `retrieve_connection'
  activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:142:in `connection'
  activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:67:in `rescue in call'
  activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/query_cache.rb:61:in `call'
  activerecord (3.2.0) lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_pool.rb:443:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:28:in `block in call'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `_run__186077810047649794__call__2115495702768811851__callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_call_callbacks'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/callbacks.rb:27:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/reloader.rb:65:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/remote_ip.rb:31:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/debug_exceptions.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/show_exceptions.rb:56:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:26:in `call_app'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/logger.rb:16:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/request_id.rb:22:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/methodoverride.rb:21:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/runtime.rb:17:in `call'
  activesupport (3.2.0) lib/active_support/cache/strategy/local_cache.rb:72:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/lock.rb:15:in `call'
  actionpack (3.2.0) lib/action_dispatch/middleware/static.rb:53:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/engine.rb:479:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/application.rb:220:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/content_length.rb:14:in `call'
  railties (3.2.0) lib/rails/rack/log_tailer.rb:14:in `call'
  rack (1.4.1) lib/rack/handler/webrick.rb:59:in `service'
  /Users/aren/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:111:in `service'
  /Users/aren/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/httpserver.rb:70:in `run'
  /Users/aren/.rvm/rubies/ruby-1.9.2-p290/lib/ruby/1.9.1/webrick/server.rb:183:in `block in start_thread'


  Rendered /Users/aren/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_trace.erb (1.8ms)
  Rendered /Users/aren/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/_request_and_response.erb (39.4ms)
  Rendered /Users/aren/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/actionpack-3.2.0/lib/action_dispatch/middleware/templates/rescues/diagnostics.erb within rescues/layout (54.0ms)
```

How do I fix the above issue? Why is an ActiveRecord database connection even trying to be established?

Thanks again!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Maybe comment this two lines

```
config/environments/development.rb:  

# config.active_record.mass_assignment_sanitizer = :strict
# config.active_record.auto_explain_threshold_in_seconds = 0.5
```

Comment: You're right. When I'm commented below lines it's working fine.

Answer (score 18):

You're probably setting some `config.active_record` settings somewhere in your config folder (`development.rb`, `test.rb`, etc). You'll want to comment out these settings since you're not using ActiveRecord.

You can do something like `grep -r active_record config/` in your project folder to find files referencing `active_record`.

**Update**: Make sure you have removed the `require 'rails/all'` line from `config/application.rb` as well. The new `require` lines you added are supposed to replace that line. Otherwise, `rails/all` still loads ActiveRecord.

Comment: See the above update I made - I removed all references of active_record from any file in the config folder, yet I still am getting ActiveRecord errors.

Comment: See my updated answer. I'm thinking you forgot to remove the `rails/all` require line.