# Rails4 application with just mongoid and no database

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid

I am trying to develop a mongo only api application with rails. After removing the sqlite gem and database configuration I am getting following error:
Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`: Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"]

When I put an empty file there, it gives me an error about not finding development database adapter.

I am using mongo and I will never be using a rdbms, how can I get rid of these errors, one solution is to keep dummy database, but it would create trouble when deploying to heroku.

How can I setup mongoid correctly, so that the application does not asks me for a traditional database configuration?

Comment: You should put mongoid.yml in config folder with all the db details.

Comment: Delete your mongoid.yml and run this `rails g mongoid:config` and it should be fine.

Comment: still getting: `database_configuration': Cannot load `Rails.application.database_configuration`:
Could not load database configuration. No such file - ["config/database.yml"] (RuntimeError)

Comment: also cant even run the config command without the database.yml

Comment: put database.yml back in place and then run the command. delete later on.

Comment: Referencing [9012352](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012352/removing-database-yml-when-using-mongoid-in-rails-3-2).

Answer (score 1):

Find a good answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9012352/removing-database-yml-when-using-mongoid-in-rails-3-2). Basically you have to comment out all the references to "active_record" in the config folder.